# Spring boot: how to specify a main class located in the internal lib

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I am packaging my spring boot application into a jar file using "spring-boot-maven-plugin" and I need to point to a mainClass which resides in my-internal-lib.jar.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>my.internal.lib.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Folder structure of generated jar is as follows:

```
-- com
   -- my
      -- spring
          -- boot
              RestRunner.java
              App.java 

-- lib 
    -- my-internal-lib.jar (my.internal.lib.Main.java)

-- META-INF 
    -- maven
    -- MANIFEST.MF
-- org 
application.properties
```

And my code is something like this:

```
package my.internal.lib;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new RestRunner().start(args);           
    }
}

package com.my.spring.boot;
public class RestRunner{

    public boolean start(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}

package com.my.spring.boot;
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.my.spring.boot"})
public class App {}
```

And my MANIFEST.MF is as follows:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Built-By: ...
Start-Class: my.internal.lib.Main
Spring-Boot-Version: 1.3.2.RELEASE
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_112
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

But I get this error while running the jar using command **"java -cp myjar.jar my.internal.lib.Main"**:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.internal.lib.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Is my internal jar in the classpath? if not, how to add it?

Comment: Can you show how is your Main class defined?

Comment: If repackage fails, how do you get the generated jar?

Comment: repackage doesn't fail, I get the error while starting my app.

Comment: What is in meta-inf ?

Comment: Run it with Java - jar jarname

Comment: Why not using java -jar jarFileName instead of java -cp?

Answer (score 1):

The problem solved using "java -jar jarname".
Thanks to @Alexander.Furer